# Java Shortest Path general solution

Tags: java, path, shortest

The 'p' is the number of nodes. So now in my solution the user has to type in all the matrix elements, in case of 7 nodes, 49 numbers. I don't want it this way. I would like to ask the user the distances from one point to the other. Sorry for the weird names in my program, they're in my language. latogatott = visited, tav=distance

```
package legrovidebb_ut;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Legrovidebb_ut {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Adja meg a pontok szamat: ");

    int p;

    p = scan.nextInt( );

    int[][] matrix = new int [p][p];
    int[] tav = new int[p];
    int[] latogatott = new int[p];
    int[] pre = new int[p];
    int min;
    int nextNode = 0;


    System.out.println("Enter the matrix!");


    for (int i=0; i<p; i++){

        latogatott[i]=0;

        pre[i]=0;

        for (int j=0;j<p;j++){

            matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            if(matrix[i][j]== 0)
                matrix[i][j]=999;
        }
    }
    tav = matrix[0];
    tav[0]=0;
    latogatott[0]=1;

    for (int i=0;i<p;i++){
        min=999;

    for(int j=0;j<p;j++){
        if(min>tav[j] && latogatott[j]!=1){

            min=tav[j];
            nextNode=j;
        }
    }
    latogatott[nextNode]=1;

    for(int c=0;c<p;c++){
        if(latogatott[c]!=1){
            if(min+matrix[nextNode][c]<tav[c]){
                tav[c]=min+matrix[nextNode][c];
                pre[c]=nextNode;
            }
        }
    }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<p;i++){
        System.out.print("|" + tav[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("|");

    for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
        int j;
        System.out.print("Ut: " + (i+1));
        j=i;

        do{
            j=pre[j];
            System.out.println(" <- " + (j+1));
        }while(j!=0);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So what's your question? How you can make the user to input the distances?

Comment: yes, cos it is already quite complicated, I would need to change it as inputs from the user: The distance between 1 to 2: , 1-3, 1-4....   and not asking again 2-1 cos it is already given, 2-3, 2-4 and so on

Comment: That's only already given if your graph is an undirected graph. In this case, you would have to loop through every node of the graph and make an inner loop, which loops through all with higher indexes, i.e. something like:

    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
      for(int k=i+1; k < p; k++) {
        // ask for distance between i and k
      }
    }

This way you only ask for 1-2, 1-3, 1-4,..., 1-n, 2-3, 2-4,... but never for 1-2 and 2-1.

Comment: Okay, I see code is not readable in a comment... so I'll add an answer

Answer (score 0):

If your graph is undirected and you want the user to input the distances between each two nodes (as stated in your comment), you will need a loop through all your nodes and another loop through all the other nodes, as a distance for 2-1 is not needed if you have a distance for 1-2:

```
for(int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
  for(int k = i+1; k < p; k++) {
    // ask user for distance between i and k
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need the solution for undirected graph. Ok, I try to implement this in my code.